# Sites with big collection of ebooks in chinese language, but western titles mostly

Tags: resources

Want to know sites where one can download ebook in different formats in chinese. Interested in those resources with western titles (chinese editions) mostly. Out-of-copyright edition of western classic and modern chinese literature will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just search web, e.g. to get Chinese versions of A.Fadeev's novels The Rout (also known as The Nineteen) and The Young Guard use
法捷耶夫＋小说＋在线＋阅读 results http://www.dushu369.com/waiguomingzhu/huimie/Index.html 毁灭«Разгром»
http://yuedu.163.com/source/5e852f695e9246e2af5a554403febf57_4 青年近卫军«Молодая гвардия».

Answer (score 1):

If you are not restricted to "free ebooks only", some online ebook stores are available, like amazon.cn, book.jd.com, and book.douban.com.

As for free ebooks, it is highly unlikely to get free legal copies of the ebooks you mentioned, especially the western titles with Chinese translation. After all, China does not have a long history of EN to CN literate translation, and many of these venerated translators are still alive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind reading on your phone, you could try 网易蜗牛读书.
It has many great books that usually have to be paid to read(many that are translated from English as well). Once you register, it gives you *one hour per day* free reading time.

Or go to taobao.com and buy an eBook for as little as 1 dollar.